# Flutter How to get length of a iterable .toList() list?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, listview

I want to Display a ListView with Cards from FirebaseFirestore. Also, I want to show how many Cards there are at all:

```
int Length = 0; //?
```

How to get length of a iterable .toList() list?

```
     Column(
         children: snapshot.data!.docs
             .map(
                (doc) => 
                   Card(
                    title: doc["title"],)
                 .toList(
                growable: true,
             ),
          ),
       ),
```

Comment: just add .length at the end of it: .toList().length;

Comment: Error: The argument type 'int' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>'.

Comment: Get the length before building the widget tree, and then use it in the tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Column(
         ...snapshot.data!.docs
             .asMap().map((index, value) => MapEntry(index, Card(
                    title: value["title"],)))
                 .values.toList(
                growable: true,
             ),
          ),
```

Comment: did it help you?

Comment: can you tell me how I can set the State of the int Length for the number of the cards?

Comment: why do you need it? Your widget will be built based on the length

Comment: that's the point I want the length based on the generated length of the list? Or does this not work?

Comment: this method include itemCount, if you want get length use `snapshot.data!.docs.length`